Flutter unexpected behaviour in Navigator.pop()
I'm trying to pass a boolean value from a page to a previous one in Flutter. I try to explain briefely the scenario here:
In page A I have the following code that pushes page B and then waits for a boolean result:
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => PageB(),
  ),
).then((success) {
  log('$success');
});

In page B something really similar is done:
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => PageC(),
  ),
).then((success) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop(success);
});

And finally, in page C, the success flag is produced and returned:
function().then((success) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop(success);
});

While debugging my app with physical devices (both Android and iOS), everything works perfectly (I can see the boolean logged correctly).
As soon as I try to install the app in release mode (flutter run --release), something weird happens: it seems that the pop() in page B doesn’t work, and the app doesn’t come back to page A.
